# Create AWS Amplify Resources with Terraform

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-amplify

Is it possible to create an AWS Amplify project containing auth and storage resources using Terraform?

The goal is to link an Android client project with Amplify resources created using a Terraform template.

For example: I want to `amplify pull` from my Android Studio terminal to link the project to AWS (where the Amplify project has already been created by Terraform) and generate the configuration files.

Comment: See this PR to the terraform AWS provider: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/15966

Answer (score 2):

It might have not been the case when the question was asked, but now a `aws_amplify_app` is available as a resource type in the standard AWS provider for Terraform.

You can use:

```
resource "aws_amplify_app" "example" {
  name       = "example"
  repository = "https://github.com/example/app"
}
```

For details consult [the docs for `aws_amplify_app`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/amplify_app).